# When can the Cayley graph of the symmetries of an object have those symmetries?

Tags: gr.group-theory, graph-theory

Let $P$ be an object in $\mathbb{R}^n$ with symmetry group $G$.
Let $C$ be <strike>the</strike> a Cayley graph of $G$.

> When can $C$ be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^m$ so that the embedded graph
>   has the same symmetry group $G$ as the original object $P$?

For example, the standard Cayley graph for $D_4$, the symmetry group of
the square, can be embedded in the plane with the same symmetry:

---

[image]

          

<sup>(Image from [J.Gross](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~cs6204/).)</sup>

---

Let us view the Cayley graph
as a directed, unlabeled graph.

I would be interested in both positive and negative examples: 
$P$ such that $C$ can share the same symmetries, 
and $P$ such that none of its $C$ can realize the same symmetries.

Comment: As I understand it, there is no Cayley graph of a group G.  There is one of a group G with a given generating set S $\subseteq$ G.  (Thus I think the answer you want highly depends on S.) There may be a default case where if no generating set is specified, then G is taken also as the generating set, but then I think the graph looks less interesting.  Gerhard "Not Always Into Complete Graphs" Paseman, 2016.07.17.

Comment: for negative examples (as @GerhardPaseman implicitly mentioned): take the genertaing set to be the whole group; on gets a complete graph with symmetries $S_{|G|}$ which is (unless $|G| \leq 2$) different from $G$. In general, $G$ is always a subgroup of the automorphism group of its Cayley graphs (by acting of the left; if edges are defined by right-multiplication). Since more edges will allow for more symmetries, you should (for positive examples) always try to pick a generating set which is minimal (w.r.t. inclusion). Typical positive examples are cyclic and dihedral groups.

Comment: Also, for Abelian groups, I believe there is a paper by Clara Loeh which is relevant for your question.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman @ Antoine: Thanks for your excellent points and observations.

Comment: I do not understand why you think of the *nodes* as colored (labeled by generators)? Isn't the usual definition that the arcs are labeled by generators, and the nodes simply correspond to the group elements? And I observe that your example digraph has reflection symmetries only if you forget about the directions of the $r$-arcs.

Comment: @FriederLadisch: Good point. Altered accordingly.

Comment: @Antoine: The embedding of a graph into $\mathbb{R}^n$ can have a symmetry group which is different from the automorphism group of the graph. -- For example, a complete graph has embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^n$ whose symmetry groups are much smaller than ${\rm S}_n$, or even trivial.

Comment: @StefanKohl, On the other hand it seems to me that once $m$ gets big enough, you should be able to embed any graph into $\mathbb{R}^m$ so that the aut gp of the embedding is the same as the graph (put the vertices on orthogonal unit vectors I guess), so one should be able to start by just considering the automorphism group of the graph, as Antoine suggests.

Comment: @NickGill: You probably mean to obtain positive examples. -- What I meant is that negative examples you won't get in this way.

Comment: @StefanKohl, you're quite right, that's exactly what I was thinking. I agree with you about the negative examples.

Comment: In light of my earlier comment -- that you can ignore the embedding for large enough $m$ -- then you could just consider the question of finding **Graphical regular representations** - i.e. Cayley graphs of a group $G$ such that $Aut(\Gamma(G,S))=G$. There's a bunch of literature on this, and you might find the answer of Chris Godsil to this question interesting: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098115/when-is-the-automorphism-group-of-the-cayley-graph-of-g-just-g

Comment: @StefanKohl: I misread the question. As I read it, there was no constraint that the Cayley graph must be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is perfectly ok to speak of the symmetries of a graph without embedding it geometrically. In the "abstract" setting, Nick Gill just posted a link to a complete answer (i.e. when is are the "abstract" automorphisms exactly $G$). I would guess the geometrical question is harder. The "simple" negatives (with complete graphs, without dimension bound) persist however. Embed $G$ in $\mathbb{R}^G$ by sending each vertex to a "Dirac mass".

Comment: Thanks for the fascinating discussion, and apologies for the flawed question. I just thought it would be neat to represent the symmetries of an object by a graph with the same symmetries. Because my motivation was from geometry, indeed I was interested in geometric embeddings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Answer rewritten in view of better understanding and interesting discussion in comments:)

I first want to show that for "most" finite groups, *all* Cayley graphs of the group can be embedded into some $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that the symmetry group of the embedded Cayley graph is just $G$ (whether the Cayley graph is directed and labeled or not), and such that the natural action of $G$ on the embedded Cayley graph and the "natural" action on the Cayley graph coincide. (The last point is not true for the example in the question: $D_4$ has two orbits on the vertices of the embedded Cayley graph.)

Babai has [shown](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02429904) the following: 
If the finite group $G$ is neither abelian of exponent $>2$ nor generalized dicyclic, then there is some $v$ in some $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a representation $G\to \mathbf{O}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, such that $|G|=|Gv|$ and such that the symmetry group of the point set $Gv$ is just $G$. (Except for elementary abelian $2$-groups, Babai uses the regular representation $G\to \mathbf{O}(\mathbb{R}^{G})$ in his proof.) 
If we add line segments between $gv$ and $gsv$ corresponding to elements $s\in S$ of some generating set $S$ of $G$, then the resulting embedded Cayley graph has also symmetry group $G$, whether we consider the arcs as directed and labeled or not. (At least when we use the regular representation, these line segments will not intersect.)
This argument shows that the question concerning geometric embeddings is in fact easier than the question of *graphical regular representations*.

If, on the other hand, $G$ is abelian of exponent $>2$ or generalized dicyclic, then $G$ has an automorphism sending each group element to its inverse or itself, and which yields a symmetry of all such point orbits $Gv\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$. 
This is also a symmetry of the Cayley graphs obtained in the above way, if we forget directions of arcs. On the other hand, in these groups, each generating set must contain elements of order $>2$, so it is not a symmetry of the directed and labeled Cayley graph. But this does not completely clarify the situation for these groups, since there may be other additional symmetries (depending on the representation).

The original version of this answer contained the following special case:
Suppose that the object $P\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a convex polytope such that its symmetry group $G$ acts transitively on the vertices of $P$ (and thus $P$ is the convex hull of an orbit of a point, called an *orbit polytope*). 
Then there is some point $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $|Gv|=|G|$ (only the identity of $G$ fixes $v$) and such that  the symmetry group of $Gv$ is only $G$. (See Lemma 1 in [Babai's paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02429904) or Corollary 5.4 in [our paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1411.0899). In fact, "almost all" points have these properties.) Let $Q$ be the convex hull of $Gv$, which is another orbit polytope. The $1$-skeleton of this polytope is in a natural way (an undirected version of) a Cayley graph of $G$, where the generating set $S\subseteq G$ is the set of elements $s\in G$ such that $v$ and $sv$ are connected by an edge (a $1$-dim. face) of $Q$.
(Also revelant in this context is a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1515/CRELLE.2006.071) of Ellis, Harris and Sköldberg ([MR2270569 (2008g:20117)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2270569)).)

Answer (score 2):

[Wiki, as already in the comments]

For the easy negatives, consider the Cayley graph with respect to the generating set $S=G$. The graph obtained is then a complete graph. It can be embedded in $\mathbb{R}^{G} = \{ (a_g)_{g \in G} \mid a_g \in \mathbb{R} \}$ as follows: $g \mapsto \delta_{g\cdot}$ where $\delta_{gh} = 1$ if $h=g$ and $0$ else. The edges between two vertices all have length $\sqrt{2}$.

The permutation matrices are linear isometris of $\mathbb{R}^G$ and will permute the vertices as desired. So the symmetries of the Cayley graph contain $S_{|G|}$ which is strictly larger than $G$ as soon as $|G| \geq 2$.

More generally, as Nick Gill pointed out, this embedding shows that (without bound on $m$, or in fact, as soon as $m \geq |G|$) there is no difference between the "abstract" automorphisms and the "geometric" automorphisms.
Positive answers for "abstract" are found in this answer of C. Godsil (again, pointed out by N. Gill)  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1098115/when-is-the-automorphism-group-of-the-cayley-graph-of-g-just-g

Comment: It seems to me that you have just found one embedding of this Cayley graph which has more symmetries than $G$. But the complete graph could be embedded in another way such that its (euclidian) symmetry group is just $G$. Indeed, by the result of Babai I mentioned, when $G$ is not abelian of exponent $>2$ or generalized dicyclic, then you can embed the complete graph on $G$ into $\mathbb{R}^m$ such that its euclidian symmetry group is just $G$.

Comment: @FriederLadisch: I completely agree! I am just claiming this is a "negative" example... and also a few positive examples. Also, you can indeed loose the "obvious" embedding of $G$ in the automorphisms of a graph by embedding it. 
In fact, you can probably always embed a graph so that it has no symmetries which are euclidean isometries. To do so, just put weights in front of the Dirac masses so that no two edge have the same length...
Lastly, this answer is just a "compilation" of the comments (hence the "wiki" status)... I do not claim anything "new".

Answer (score 1):

Take $P$ to be a regular polygon on $n$ vertices, with symmetry group the dihedral group $D_n$ of order $2n$. Take the generating set to be all of $D_n$ so that the Cayley graph is the complete graph on $2n$ vertices (the generating set can be without the identity to avoid loops). This 
complete graph has a nice symmetric embedding in the plane that looks like a regular $2n$-gon with a bunch of lines connecting the vertices of the $2n$-gon through its interior. There will be lots of regular $n$-gons (by taking every other vertex of the $2n$-gon). Alter each edge of one of these interior $n$-gons in a symmetric way (say by adding a bump in the middle of each edge) so that the only plane symmetries of the embedded graph that remain are the symmetries which map the $n$-gon to itself. So this new embedding has plane symmetry group $D_n$, just as $P$ did.